# How to encrypt images in java

Tags: encryption

Need advice on this as I am still unable to encrypt /decrypt a images successfully in java.
For the user to decrypt the image, the user has to click the image and enter the image password, similar to a password protected text file or pdf file.

Below is the function for encryption Image in java

```
public static void ImgEncrypt()throws Exception{

           // Scanner to read the user's password. The Java cryptography
           // architecture points out that strong passwords in strings is a
           // bad idea, but we'll let it go for this assignment.
           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
           // Arbitrary salt data, used to make guessing attacks against the
           // password more difficult to pull off.
           byte[] salt = { (byte) 0xc7, (byte) 0x73, (byte) 0x21, (byte) 0x8c,
                   (byte) 0x7e, (byte) 0xc8, (byte) 0xee, (byte) 0x99 };

           {
      File inputFile = new File("C:/rose.jpg");
              BufferedImage input = ImageIO.read(inputFile);
              Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
              SecretKeyFactory keyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
             // Get a password from the user.
             System.out.print("Password: ");
             System.out.flush();
             PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(scanner.nextLine().toCharArray());          
             // Set up other parameters to be used by the password-based
             // encryption.
             PBEParameterSpec pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, 20);
             SecretKey pbeKey = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
             // Make a PBE Cyhper object and initialize it to encrypt using
             // the given password.
             Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
             pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeParamSpec);
             FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("C:/output.jpg");
             CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(
                    output, pbeCipher);
               //File outputFile = new File("image.png");
                 ImageIO.write(input,"JPG",cos);
              cos.close();    

    }
    }
```

Comment: If you have a question, please state it clearly. If there is a problem, please state the problem clearly. If that code throws an exception, please include the complete stack trace. *Don't* just throw a wall of code up there and hope for the best.

Comment: the program run successfully when I ran this function. However, when I opened the image file, the preview can't be shown( I assume it's encrypted). Is there a way for me to key in the password to decrypt the file, something like opening a password protected .doc or .pdf file?

Comment: code is taken from here : http://en.allexperts.com/q/Java-1046/2008/12/Reg-Image-Encryption-Decryption.htm

Answer (score 0):

The only way that you can decrypt when you open a file is when it is a self decrypting file - an executable which the operating system can run, or when the associated application contains a protocol for decryption. You cannot just click on a file you encrypted yourself and expect it to work.

Comment: wonder if there is any java libraries for software that encrypts image file such as Axcrypt? Otherwise when they get the encrypted image, they will have to download and run the java application to decrypt the encrypted image file, which is quite troublesome

Comment: I don't think there is an easy option here user1663380. If this was indeed your problem, please indicate this (and possibly vote up / accept).